# Using Json Web Tokens securely

Tags: angularjs, cookies, sails.js, passport.js, jwt

I've been searching lately on how to use **JWT** in authentication and restructuring my application to use them instead of sessions, when we came to the part of integrating server side sails api with the mobile application.

As I am building a fintech product, security matters a lot.

I am using **sails js** along with **passport-jwt**. I store the token in a browser cookie using **AngularJS $cookies.put** function. My goal here is to make sure in all ways possible that this token will not be hijacked or used from any third party in the browser to send requests to the server except the authorised user.

To protect this token I learned that I should store this cookie with **HttpOnly flag**, in order to make it unaccessible from javascript, this means I will not be able to access this token in the client side when performing ajax request, where I will need to concatenate the token in request header for passport-jwt to be able to extract it using **fromAuthHeader()** function in server side.

Another thing to do is to set **secure flag** of the cookie to be true in order to enforce that it is transmitted over SSL only.

My questions are:

1. Am I on the right track for ensuring maximum security using JWT?.
2. If yes, how to set cookie flag in angular $cookies.put method?.
3. If I will not be able to access the cookie from client side, how do
   I make passport-jwt access it from server side to authenticate?.
4. If I will be putting the token in the header, I was able to use
   angular $http interceptor to do this in ajax requests, how can I do
   this for normal browser view requests which needs authentication?.
5. Using sails CSRF protection, will it solve my problem?.

Thanks.

Links I used in my research:
https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security/
https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/

Answer (score 0):

Well, after doing more research, here is the solution I came up with for most secured authentication possible:

First of all, you have to set and get cookies in server side only (sailsJS in this case), that's why we set httpOnly flag to be true:

```
res.cookie('cookieName', jwt, {
  secure: req.connection.encrypted ? true : false,
  httpOnly: true
});
```

Notice that I am checking if current connection is secured to set secured flag in order to be able to test in development mode on localhost.

Second, for passport-jwt to be able to access the token from cookie in order to verify it, you will have to implement your custom extractor as mentioned in its repository:

> If the supplied extractors don't meet your needs you can easily
>   provide your own callback. For example, if you are using the
>   cookie-parser middleware and want to extract the JWT in a cookie you
>   could use the following function as the argument to the jwtFromRequest
>   option:

```
function cookieExtractor(req) {
    var token = null;
    if (req && req.cookies)
    {
        token = req.cookies.tokenName;
    }
    return token;
};

passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy({
        jwtFromRequest: cookieExtractor,
        secretOrKey: sails.config.jwtSettings.secret,
        issuer: sails.config.jwtSettings.issuer,
        audience: sails.config.jwtSettings.audience,
        passReqToCallback: false
    },
    function (payload, next) {
        var user = payload.user;
        return next(null, user, {});
    }));
```

Last but not least, you will need to implement CSRF security if you are going to use cookies, here is where you will be using the interceptor. First you will need to tell your sails project that you will be using csrf tokens in config/csrf.js:

```
module.exports.csrf = true;
```

Then you can use a very nice package here which will be intercepting your ajax requests and sending csrf tokens along with them  https://github.com/aditzel/spring-security-csrf-token-interceptor. But it will need a little tweaking to be functioning with sails: In spring-security-csrf-token-interceptor.js file search for this line

```
this.token = xhr.getResponseHeader(this.settings.csrfTokenHeader);
```

And replace with these two lines:

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    this.token = jsonResponse._csrf;
```

This is how will you configure the package to function with sails:

```
angapp.config(function(csrfProvider) {
    // optional configurations
    csrfProvider.config({
        url: '/csrfToken',
        csrfHttpType: 'get',
        httpTypes: ['HEAD', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'] //CSRF token will be added only to these method types
    });
});
```

**NOTE**: For traditional view forms read the comments in config/csrf.js file.

One more thing, as you are using stateless jwt authentication, you will need to store two cookies: one for authentication and holding user id as we did above, and the other for storing user info which will be used in viewing in front end and updating from the backend

```
updateUserInfoCookie: function (res, user) {
        res.cookie('user', user.toJSON(), { secure: res.connection.encrypted ? true : false, maxAge: sails.config.jwtSettings.expiresIn * 1000, signed: true, httpOnly: true });
    },
    getCurrUserInfo: function(req){
        return req.signedCookies.user;
    }
```

Hope this was clear and can be of help to someone.

Resources: https://stormpath.com/blog/build-secure-user-interfaces-using-jwts/